# Zend Cache Backend Static Remove/Clean

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-cache

I'm trying to implement a cache using Zend Cache.  I use the following code to initialize the caches.

```
$tagCache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core',
                                'File',
                                 array('automatic_serialization' => true),
                                 array('cache_dir' => $cfg['instdir']. 'Cache_dir'));

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Capture',
                             'Static',
                              array(),
                              array('index_filename' => 'index',
                                    'public_dir'     => $cfg['instdir'] . 'Cached',
                                    'tag_cache'      => $tagCache));
```

---

I use the following code to start caching:

```
$id = bin2hex($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$cache->start($id, array());
```

The cache files are generated but I can't delete them using the `remove()` method (the cache doesn't refresh):

```
$cache->remove($id); // id generated like above from the REQUEST_URI of the page I want to refresh
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are there any permission related errors outputting to your error log? And did you validate that the $id values are exactly the same? (for start() and remove())

Comment: I don't get any errors in my logs. I've checked the ids ... I even created a test file with some hard coded values for the ids. But no luck.  I've opened some of the cache files and they seem to be created as they should...but when I want to remove them nothing happens. The cache directories have the necessary read, write permissions.

Comment: Are you wrapping a try/catch block around the remove() call? You may have to dig around their API docs to uncover the problem.

Comment: It turns out that you have to pass the path to the cache file to the remove method in order for it to work. Although the Zend Documentation says it takes a cache id.anyway if anyone else has a similar problem .... just add $id = $this->_decodeId($id); to the remove method in the Static.php backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$cache->remove()` is a proxy to the backend's `remove()` method. In this case you are using the `Static` backend and so we look in there to find out what's happening.

My reading of that method leads me to believe that the `$id` parameter to `remove` has to be a filename, so:

```
$cache->remove('index');
```

will work.

The more usual way to clear a cache is to use the `clean()` method though. See [the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.theory.html#zend.cache.clean).

Comment: That's a broken link :/